# Referencing Google's scoreboard

Tags: javascript, swift, google-search

If you Google search "NFL Scores" you'll see that there is a div that contains the scores for the NFL.

https://www.google.com/search?q=nfl+scores&oq=nfl+scores&aqs=chrome.0.0l2j69i60j0l3.2165j1j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Is there any way of loading just that div and not the search results?

***What I've tried:***

I can easily load the webview, and then parse it for the specific div that shows the scores and then display that only with the "loadHTMLString" method, but then I'll lose reference to the css files in the rest of the html doc.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but is there a reason you can't use the NFL APIs?

Comment: I can..but I really don't want to build all of that when I can just load google's. There's is really well organized.

Comment: Google may not like that; I'd suggest using an API.